# How to show list items got selected in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a number of  list items like sports, music, dance etc. I also have images related to them. What I want to do is, when I click on the image of sports, the list item 'sports' seen selected. I am a beginner in java script and do not understand how to make this possible.

Comment: My imagination is limited. can you please share the code which you tried?

Comment: yes post your code

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Post the code here

Comment: My code is here..
<div class="menulist">
<ul>
<li>sports</li>
<li>music</li>
<li>dance</li></ul>


code for images:
<div class="image-item">
   <img src="sports.jpg">
<div class="image-item">
    <img src="music.jpg">
<div class="image-item">
    <imge src="dance.jpg">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a working approach for your, very information missing, question. I wrote this to show you how it CAN work so you can adapt my solution to your code.

JS:

```
$('img').click(function() {
    match = $(this).attr("match");

    $('select').val(match);
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="1.jpg" match="sport"/>
<img src="2.jpg" match="dance"/>

<select name="list" value="">
    <option value="sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="dance">Dance</option>
</select>
```

Here you can see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lw2gupj/2/

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript you can do it like this, you can find jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/rayalofuva/edit?html,js,output)

JS

```
(function(){
var hobby=document.getElementById('hobby');
var list=document.getElementById('imageCollection');
list.addEventListener('click',function(event){
        hobby.value=event.target.name;
    },true);
})();
```

HTML

```
<select name="hobby" id="hobby">
    <option value="sports">Sports</option>
    <option value="dance">Dance</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
</select>
<ul id="imageCollection">
    <li><img src="sports.jpg" alt="Sports" name="sports" />
    </li>
    <li><img src="dance.jpg" name="dance" alt="Dance" />
    </li>
    <li><img src="music.jpg" name="music" alt="Music" />
    </li>
</ul>
```